# Разница между конкретными примерами обработки ответов на запросы через fetch в JS

Tags: javascript, fetch

В чем принципиальная разница между двумя кодами с использованием функций getData1 и getData2 и являются ли эти два кода взаимозаменяемыми:

1)

```js
const getData1 = (url) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => resolve(json))
      .catch((error) => reject(error))
  );

getData1('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

2)

```js
const getData2 = (url) =>
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

getData2('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
```

Comment: В первом случае вы, кажется, сами можете приладить свой обработчик как на случай успеха, так и в случае ошибки, во втором примере, очевидно всё заранее зашито в функцию.  Если вам надо по-разному обрабатывать те или иные данные, удобнее пользоваться первым вариантом. Так я думаю.

Comment: Первый метод можно сократить на три строки и лишний промиз убрав вторую, пятую и шестую строки. Во втором методе подумайте о том что обычно данные нужно куда-то получить, а не просто вывести в консоль.